# parse vsftpd log with shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script

I try to parse this line with vsftpd:

`Sun Apr  7 07:23:33 2013 [pid 23590] [cam02430] OK UPLOAD: Client "206.132.183.209", "/20130407/07/20130407_072324D.avi", 496846 bytes, 383.38Kbyte/sec`

with:

```
cut -d" " -f9 | sed 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/'
```

This parses out the username successfully which is: `cam02430`

But now the date has changed:

`Wed Apr 10 10:37:50 2013 [pid 26137] [cam02299] OK UPLOAD: Client "206.132.183.201", "/20130410/10/20130410_103802D.avi", 496838 bytes, 363.67Kbyte/sec`

Now to parse this I have to use:

```
cut -d" " -f8 | sed 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/'
```

Is there a better way to parse the username in one line? I'd like to stick to a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct is to isolate the user portion (using `grep -o`). The good thing about it is that it has some (relatively) unique marking - the brackets.

So, the grep below isolates the (two) fields that have brackets around them, then takes out the first field (process ID) then strips the bracket off of what's left (user field)

```
 < vsftp.log grep -o '\[[^]]*\] *\[[^]]*\]' | sed -e 's/\[[^]]*\] *//' -e 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/'
```

If you can guarantee there are no spaces in the user name, you can take advantage and simplify things a bit. Find the bracketed field without spaces (the pid field would have them) and then do the trim.

```
< vsftp.log grep -o '\[[^] ]*\]' | sed -e 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/'
```

It works, though may not be optimal.

Comment: I can guarantee the usernames have no spaces. Thanks.